What type of mold is this and is it dangerous to human and pets? How can I get rid of mold?

I put the in bathroom and this is what I got after 4 days.
Can you tell me what type of mold that is, is it dangerous to humans and animals and how did I get rid of it

This method isn't useful for the purpose you want because there are mold spores everywhere all the time and there's no getting rid of them.
